# A word meaning collaborate

Tags: collocation

Looking for a short(ish) word approximating "collaborate." The word might also be a clever metaphor or symbol for the idea of collaborating / working as one.

Comment: to **ally** may work

Comment: *Collaborate* is but eleven letters long. Not exactly long. Synonyms for *collaborate* can be looked up in a thesaurus of your liking. But synonyms only work in context, of which you supplied none. Failing that, the only word that reliably means *collaborate* is *collaborate*. No other word means exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

There are two contrasting meanings to collaborate.

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/collaborate)

> : to work with another person or group in order to achieve or do something
>
> : to give help to an enemy who has invaded your country during a war

For the positive meaning, short words available are join, team and ally.

For the negative meaning, I actually like the word scheme. Other short words that can work are plot and cahoots.

It is beyond me to find a short-word metaphor for collaboration but "the second mouse gets the cheese" is pretty logical. And funny.

Answer (score 0):

Short and informal could be **co-op**, although it's an abbreviation of *cooperate*.

Answer (score 0):

What about **to coact**,

```
To act together; to work in concert.
```

Answer (score 0):

How about *combine*?

> *HGC and Big Sky Fire Protection [combined](http://heritagecontracting.us/project-photo-gallery/) on this project.*

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest **together**,

> ***[together](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/together)***
>   - used for saying that people are with each other or are doing something with each other
>   - if people are together, come together, etc., they work with each other and do not oppose each other
>   - considered as a whole